# Ist "Würde mich zu hören freuen..." eigentlich korrekt?

Tags: grammar

Gegeben sei der Satz:

> Es würde mich **freuen, zu hören,** wie das Spiel ausgegangen ist

Wäre die Formulierung

> Es würde mich **zu hören freuen**, wie das Spiel ausgegangen ist

eigentlich auch korrekt?

Answer (score 1):

"Es würde mich zu hören freuen" sounds unusual and seems to suggest that the sentence is over. I would like to make a suggestion as to why this is the case.

Perhaps we can think of the sentence as consisting of two parts:

> **I**: (**1**) Ich würde mich freuen (**2**) zu hören wie das Spiel ausgegangen ist.

Your construction with "zu hören freuen" is rather chiastic, going back and forth between the two parts:

> **II**: (**1**) Ich würde mich (**2**) zu hören (**1**) freuen (**2**) wie das Spiel ausgegangen ist.

In this sense **II** is less linear and smooth than **I** even if it may be formally possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Die erste Variante klingt definitiv moderner** und, wie von Constantin beschrieben, runder. Korrekt sind sie beide.

Mann könnte einen leichten Unterschied in der Bedeutung sehen:

Beim ersten Satz soll ausgedrückt werden, dass es erfreulich wäre über das Ergebnis des Spiels informiert zu werden.

Beim zweiten Satz wird das Verb *hören* prominenter platziert und ich fände ein Konstruktion mit **dass** sinnvoller:

> Es würde mich zu hören freuen, dass Sie das Spiel gewonnen haben.

Interpretation: ein Ergebnis wurde *erwartet* und man freut sich es endlich *hören* zu dürfen.